# Exception at 0x751fc52f, code: 0x71a: , flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I get the error in subject line when I *debug* my Qt application (using Qt Creator 3.6.0)

I don't get it when I build and run but only when I debug it. It seems like because of this, my debugger is acting funky as well, sometime it doesn't step into the code, other time it does, specially when restart Qt Creator.

More importantly there is no clue where this exception is happening. How can i get to this exception and possibly have the debugger stop where it is occurring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can i get to this exception and possibly have the debugger stop
>   where it is occurring?

Qt Creator can set the specific debug mode for that. Depending on specific debugger "Break on exception":

[image]

Mind that Qt Creator uses external debuggers and specialized IDEs like Visual Studio or xCode have better control over debug options. MS Visual Studio, for instance, recognizes several types of exceptions including C++ and many more but here you have just general 'C++ exceptions'. Visual Studio debugger-handled types of exceptions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that should do but I am no longer getting the exception after making some changes. But I will keep an eye and accept this answer if I was able to verify.

Comment: I didn't get this error again to verify but I accepted this as answer since it has been voted up by others and has helped.

Comment: For Qt Creator version 9 and above, this option is present under `Edit -> Preferences`

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same weird errors in the console when debugging on Windows using Qt Creator **v7**.  I had to disable the options to "Add Exceptions to Issue View" in the CDB (Microsoft Console Debugger) settings.  See the screen shot (snapped after unchecking the boxes, thereby eliminating the issue).

[image]